# mysql join on two indexes takes long time!

Tags: mysql, drupal, inner-join

Hi All
I have a custom query in dripal, this query is:

```
select count(distinct B.src) 
from node A, url_alias B 
where concat('node/',A.nid)= B.src;
```

now, nid in node is primary key and i have made src as an index in url_alias table.
after waiting for more than a minute i got this:

```
+-----------------------+  
| count(distinct B.src) |  
+-----------------------+  
|                325715 |  
+-----------------------+  
1 row in set (1 min 24.37 sec)
```

by checking "explain" i got this:

```
******************* 1. row ***************************  
           id: 1  
  select_type: SIMPLE  
        table: A  
         type: index  
possible_keys: NULL  
          key: PRIMARY  
      key_len: 4  
          ref: NULL  
         rows: 325716  
        Extra: Using index  
*************************** 2. row ***************************  
           id: 1  
  select_type: SIMPLE  
        table: B  
         type: ALL  
possible_keys: src_language_pid,src  
          key: NULL  
      key_len: NULL  
          ref: NULL  
         rows: 325928  
        Extra: Range checked for each record (index map: 0xC)  
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

now my question is: why did this query didnt use the index of src, and how to optimize it??

Thanks for your help

Comment: You're using a function in your JOIN condition (which is in fact in WHERE clause in your case, but gets rewritten to a JOIN before the query is run) which means a query can not use any indexes for this join.

Answer (score 1):

The performance problem is related to the use of `concat`
If nid is an integer this lead to a lot of job.

I think you have to add an indexed nid column in url_alias.

Unfortunately your table will not be anymore normalized.

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT(DISTINCT something)` will, for non trivial queries and if no unique index exists on the counted expression, force the query to build an unique index on it while running the query.

This is inherently slow and in most cases either:

- not necessary - solution: rewrite query so that distinct is not needed
- if it is really necessary to use unique then still often it is faster to break the query in two, one that will get the useful results of the query that would create duplicates of `B.src` and another query that will not need distinct

Finally, learn to use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html), so you can start to learn how are your queries executed and how to optimize them.

Answer (score 0):

1) make an explain of this query, launch it with EXPLAIN SLECT count....

2) try to move your join condition (the where) as a join:

```
 select count(distinct B.src) from node A inner join url_alias B ON concat('node/',A.nid)=B.src
```

3) to be fast the indexed thing should be "concat('node/',nid)" in the node table. Here this thing must be recomptuded for each row of node. Depending on your version of MySQL you'll maybe cannot build an index with an expression (just columns). So you could have a column dedicated to store "concat('node/',nid)" and you could call it node_nid and index it. And check that you do not already get it!